# Chaining scope methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have a problem when uploading new photos.

I have a scope named :most_tagged, which works apparently fine.
Photos are shown by most_tagged DESC, but, when I upload a new photo that has 0 tags, it goes to the top(shows before the most tagged photo) instead than going to the bottom and show the last after the less tagged photo.

Should I chain another method to the most_tagged scope?

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags , dependent: :destroy
  before_destroy { |record| record.tags.destroy_all if record.tags.any? }

  scope :most_tagged, -> { order('tags_count DESC') }
  scope :most_liked, -> { order('cached_votes_up DESC') }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the content of the `most_tagged` scope please?

Comment: posting all the model file can help alot

Comment: I removed the irrevelant pieces of code, I hope I did not removed too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `NULLS LAST` option:

```
scope :most_tagged, -> { order('tags_count DESC NULLS LAST') }
```

Comment: That made the trick! What does that do exactly? Isn't it a bit hacky? Or is it the best practice?

Comment: `NULLS LAST` functions speaks by itself... It puts the `NULL` values of the column ordered in the `LAST` position. It is not hacky to do this, it is standard SQL behavior.